# Importing a library in Xcode

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I'm having trouble adding a third party library to my Xcode project. I have already downloaded the library, uncompressed it and saved it on my Desktop. So I have a folder called mpfr-3.1.2 (mpfr is the name of the library) which contains a lot of files. How can I add this library to my Xcode project? I have tried several things but none of them seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html  This link give you the whole documentation to install library...

Answer (score 0):

In the project navigator, select the project or group within a project to which you want to add the framework.

Choose File > Add Files to “”.

Select the framework bundle, and click Add.

Hope this one works...

Answer (score 0):

Drag the library into your project and check Destination on
[image]